Where was this nature scene in The Good Doctor S05E08 filmed?
Where was this scene of stairs in The Good Doctor season 5, episode 8 (2 minute mark in the episode) filmed?
Given the filming location of the series, it is probably somewhere in Vancouver.


China Creek North Park, looking north east.
The park is north west of Vancouver Community College - Broadway Campus
References below:

Reference remarks:
Acorn lamps are set additions (set dressing) for filming
Low building in background is Tesla Delivery Center, 901, Great Northern Way
Billboard places approximate time of filming as July 2023
https://www.latlong.net/location/the-good-doctor-locations-493
https://thecinemaholic.com/where-was-the-good-doctor-filmed/
https://moviemaps.org/locations/4nx
In this scene, same location, night, the camera pans around so that the West Softball Diamond is seen in the background.



 (03:26)

An excellent find. Well done
